# Difference between PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sWriter) and Printwriter out = response.getWriter()

Tags: java, servlets

```
StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sWriter);

out.println("Hello World");
response.getWriter().print(sWriter.toString());
```

OR

```
Printwriter out = response.getWriter();
```

1. What is difference between these two while we use them in Java Servlet
2. Which one is efficient in Servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sWriter);

out.println("Hello World");
response.getWriter().print(sWriter.toString());
```

This creates a `StringWriter` that is independent of the response. It creates a `String` with the content you put in it and then takes that and puts it into `PrintWriter` of the response.

```java
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

This just gets the `PrintWriter` that writes to the response.

If you write to that, it is directly given to the response.

The second method is more efficient because java doesn't have to create a single String with your whole content but can directly deliver it.